# vue this.array.find in methods/computed properties gives undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an array (approvalOptions) that i receive from getters in a component, from which i need to find a certain value.

Things i have tried:

1. Use it in methods (read from ...mapGetters) like so

```
methods: {
    approvalDisplayName(value) {
      console.log(this.approvalOptions)
      return this.approvalOptions.find(it => it.key === value).displayName;
    },
  },
```

2. use it in computed (read from ...mapGetters) (code sample same as above, only difference being the use of computed properties' block instead of methods'
3. use it in methods (read from data properties) like so

```
data() {
   return {
   approvalOptions: [...(objects with keys and values here)]
   }
 },
methods: {
   approvalDisplayName(value) {
     console.log(this.approvalOptions)
     return this.approvalOptions.find(it => it.key === value).displayName;
   },
 },
```

All three times I get an error in the console that approvalOptions.find(...) doesnt exist. The console.log also prints an array in the console so i really don't understand what is going on here.

Comment: Please share the `this.approvalOptions` and `value`

Comment: i dont think its important what the real data is. approvalOptions is an array of objects with keys and values (which are in-turn strings) and the value parameter to the function in also a string. 
However they should have no influence on whether the method find exists on the approvalOptions or not, correct?

Comment: If you are sure that `approvalOptions` is array, then `array#find` will work. You can check if value exist in the your array and it is returning an object.

Comment: There's not enough context to reproduce the problem. Can you share a link to a reproduction (e.g., in Codesandbox, Codepen, StackBlitz, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you

```
computed: {
    approvalOptions() {
      return [
        { key: 1, displayName: "Name 1" },
        { key: 2, displayName: "Name 2" }
      ];
    }
  },
  methods: {
    approvalDisplayName(options, value) {
      return options.find((it) => it.key === value).displayName;
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.approvalDisplayName(this.approvalOptions, 1));
  }
```